# PHP version of CSS Media Queries

Tags: php, css, media-queries

Can't find anything on the web for this, wanted to throw the question out there.

Is the a PHP version of CSS Media Queries?

Comment: I'm sorta curious though, what are you trying to achieve?

Comment: using MobileESP and wanted to target specific resolutions not just the device itself with PHP

Comment: I think you'd have to revert to javascript at that stage. Make an asynchronous request back to the server with specifics and you could then theoretically load in a new/updated/environment-specific stylesheet based on that data. But you'll really still have to gather up the parameters you want yourself, send them to the server and decide what to swap out following it. So nowhere near as clean as CSS with media queries. But far more flexible and customizable I guess.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'm under the assumption that you would want to do this for the purpose of detecting mobile browsers - if not, then this answer is slightly irrelevant.

You can check out [Mobile ESP](http://code.google.com/p/mobileesp/) for a mobile User Agent detection library. It's very simple to use and works well in my experiences.

Comment: Yeah I've looked at this and I like it but it doesn't offer specific device detection. Wanted to combine this with CSS Media Queries to offer specific functionality to the mobile device such as , iPhone 4 retina display. I know I can do this with CSS but I wanted to load it dynamically to keep the file size down

Comment: Just in case anyone else wants to go this route, check out https://github.com/serbanghita/Mobile-Detect

Answer (score 2):

No, there isn't.

The browser doesn't send information on any of its [media features](http://www.w3.org/TR/css3-mediaqueries/#media1) to the server, so PHP doesn't have the information needed to implement this.

Answer (score 2):

I've used a method (found on http://php.net/manual/en/faq.html.php Example #4) that combines javascript and php to achieve an alternative for media queries. I achieve this by using javascript embedded inside my php to post a variable (screen.width) that is then used by php to determine breakpoints for loading stylesheets. Include the following snippet into your head tag:

```
<?php
  if (isset($_GET['width'])) {
    $width = $_GET['width'];
    if ($width <= 480) { //mobile devices
      $style = '<link rel="stylesheet" href="mobile.css" type="text/css">';
    } elseif ($width <= 720){ //tablets
      $style = '<link rel="stylesheet" href="tablet.css" type="text/css">';
    } else { //desktops
      $style = '<link rel="stylesheet" href="desktop.css" type="text/css">';
    }
    echo $style;
  } else {
      echo "<script language='javascript'>\n";
      echo "  location.href=\"${_SERVER['SCRIPT_NAME']}?${_SERVER['QUERY_STRING']}" . "&width=\" + screen.width; \n";
      echo "</script>\n";
      exit();
  }
?>
```

I found using this method was also more efficient on the content load of a page, unlike media queries (which will load the CSS styles for all devices even when it's not necessary - ie mobile devices still get desktop styles loaded). This method ensures that stylesheets get loaded specific to the device alone, assuming you have a stylesheet that has common styling for all media devices.

Comment: Suvi Vignarahah   Thanks for sharing this.  I've been looking for a way to detect media query's using php.  Awesome!!!

Answer (score 1):

You may be able to check out `$_SERVER['HTTP_USER_AGENT']` and make a decision based on what you find there. There may be a library out there somewhere that's already taken care of this, but I'm not aware of one off the top of my head.

Answer (score 1):

There is the [get_browser](http://php.net/get_browser) php function you can use to determine some browser capabilities. But that's not the same like the media queries. The css media queries are conditional to the devices display measurements. The php function does not return such informations.